# T-SQL: How to return white color-code when standard deviation is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    SELECT a.Month,
           a.Category,
           a.Count_Number AS Count_Result,
           ISNULL(b.AvgCount,0) AS Monthly_AVG,
           ISNULL(b.Count_Stdev,0) AS Count_STDEV,
           ISNULL(b.Max_Count,0) AS Max_Count,
           ISNULL(b.Min_Count,0) AS MIN_Count,
           function_01.n.fn_get_color_code (ISNULL(a.Count_Number,0),ISNULL(b.AvgCount,0),ISNULL(b.Count_STDEV,0),ISNULL(b.Max_Count,0),ISNULL(b.MIN_Count,0),@Sigma,0) AS Count_Color
    FROM #number1 AS a with (nolock)
    LEFT JOIN #CountAVG as b with (nolock) on a.Category=b.Category
    ORDER BY a.Month ASC
```

I am having the a part of the SQL-code as above, what I would like the result to return white color or no color when the standard deviation `Count_STDEV`=0, how should I write the code? I am using `T-SQL`.

.

Answer (score 0):

You would add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE b.Count_Stdev = 0 OR b.Count_Stdev IS NULL
```